# OwinHost.exe vs Custom Host

Tags: c#, asp.net, owin, host, katana

Katana has 3 popular Host:
?

1. IIS/ASP.NET
2. Custom Host
3. OwinHost.exe

My question is what is the difference between Custom Host and OwinHost.exe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom Host: You host your own services (Web API) in your own application/service.

OwinHost.exe: available in nuget for hosting OWIN based applications